# Looking for LaTeX-based images of cowboys and cowgirls

Tags: diagrams

Odd request, but is there  one? 
[This is the closest I found.](http://tex-talk.net/2016/11/tikz-people/)

Comment: Given that there already is a cowboy in the linked package I do not understand what you are asking? Are you looking for a cowgirl which looks similar to the cowboy? Are you unhappy about the existing cowboy?

Comment: @MarcelKrüger A cowgirl in the same package would be nice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The articlelinked in your question discusses `tikzpeople`. That package provides a cowboy and also has an option to make female cowboys, aka. cowgirls. We can use `cowgirl/.style` to define `cowgirl` as an alias for `cowboy, female`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpeople}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[cowgirl/.style = {cowboy,female}]
  \node[cowboy, minimum size=1cm] at (0,0) {};
  \node[cowgirl, mirrored, minimum size=1cm] at (2cm,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]